# What are the other ways (if they exist) that atoms can gain or lose electrons that aren't bonding?

Tags: bond, electrons

I know that electrons can be isolated through human intervention from their atoms. My question rather concerns if electrons are ever lost or gained naturally. I recognize that this is a stupid question but I couldn't find the answer on the Internet.

Comment: *Transferring* electrons between atoms is quite normal, but creating or destroying electrons outright is a different matter. That depends on what you count as natural. Does radioactive decay count?

Comment: See [electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture), [beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_decay), and [electron-positron pair production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production#Photon_to_electron_and_positron)

Comment: At high temperature everything loses electron and cannot stay in the bonded state. Check the term plasma.

Comment: Also [x-ray fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_fluorescence), and [Auger effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auger_effect)

Comment: And photoionization -- in the beginning, all was ionized...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photoionization

Answer (score 2):

> My question rather concerns if electrons are ever lost or gained **naturally**.

Yes, they can!

Here are two examples of natural processes by which atoms can gain or lose electrons "naturally":

### Electron Capture

In the *natural radioactive decay process* known as [electron capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture) the nucleus captures an inner-shell electron, K- or sometimes L-shell. This results in a proton being converted to a neutron, and the emission of a neutrino. The atom has lost an electron, but conveniently a proton as well, so it remains neutral but with a deep vacancy.

### Auger Process

If the vacancy is filled by a higher shell electron falling into it this can result in the emission of a photon, or in the emission of yet another electron. That emission is referred to as the [Auger process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auger_effect).

---

See [Electron capture; Reaction_details](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_capture#Reaction_details) for examples.

[image] [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Atomic_rearrangement_following_an_electron_capture.svg)